# Access js function outside a frame from a different domain

Tags: html-frames

I have several frames (**not iframe**) inside a page. One of the frames is from a different domain from the main website. If my website is example.com, there is an frame with source example2.com. I have a function on the main page. I would like to call this function from the frame. `window.parent.swapFrame()` but it shows the obvious security error.

Comment: _“but it shows the obvious security error”_ – and this (called Same Origin Policiy) is exactly why this _can’t be done_ (unless the page from the other domain would explicitly implement measures for you to be able to call their methods).

Comment: the reason I said "obvious security error" is because I knew the reason and that a browser needs to give the error. I knew someone is going to say its a different domain and it cant be done. 

Anyways in this case both are my domains. There must be some work around for my domain to allow access to mine